# Is it possible to use dash framework with existing mod_python framework or pyramid framework to deploy dash's graphical feature on a web page?

Tags: python, pyramid, plotly-dash, mod-python, graphical-interaction

I'm trying to test out graphical features such as graphs and charts to be added to a web page. I am wondering if it is possible to use the dash framework with the existing frameworks that I know such as mod_python and pyramid to create these graphic features.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's totally possible, you can follow this guide: https://dash.plot.ly/integrating-dash

Dash is built on top of Flask so it's relatively easy to add Dash to a Flask app. It would require a bit of effort to add it to other framework like Pyramid or Django.

P/S: `mod_python` is a Apache module, not a Python framework